# Using Flask-pymongo across multiple modules

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I'm having some trouble understanding how to incorporate Flask-Pymongo. My app is initiated from my `rrapp.py` Inside of this file, I have

**rrapp.py**

```
#
# Imports up here
#

app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

# Code down here
```

Now, to use this, I simply do `mongo.db.users.find()`. This works fine.

Now, say I have another file called `userservice.py` that I call methods from one of my endpoints within `rrapp.py`. How do I incorporate `PyMongo(app)` in my `userservice.py` file if I don't have access to the `app` object? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: i have a `config.py` in a `config` folder and a def connect() function.  i just fo `from config import config` and do `config.connect()`.  then i can set `db = config.connect()` and go `results = db.doc.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

- you should first define mongo oustside create_app to have access to it from inside other files.
- then init_app with that like the following:

from flask import Flask, current_app

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

mongo = PyMongo()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])

    # INIT EXTENSIONS ----------------------

    mongo.init_app(app)

    return app
```

then in any file you can import mongo from above file. for example:

```
from ../factory import mongo
```